# Why code after Await does not run on UI thread?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have used delegates in the past to update the current UI (for example a textbox) with a value that is being processed in my thread.  I was under the assumption that `async` and `await` took care of this for you.

When I run the code below -when the button is pressed start a new task that will count up to 100 every 100ms.  The count should be displayed on the UI, but I get a targetInvocationException instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = "Press button";
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         await Task1();
    }

    private Task Task1()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CountMethod());
    }

    private void CountMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
            //Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code `textBox1.Text = ...` is not after the `await`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you are using a thread-pool thread to access the UI. You are doing this by using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
private async Task Task1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

`await` will capture the current [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) so that after the asynchronous wait is complete, the code that follows executes on the UI thread. This is true because `await` was called by the UI thread (in the case of my example).

In your current code, `await` is called on a thread-pool thread. In this case the current `SynchronizationContext` is null and therefore the code that follows the asynchronous wait will be executed also on a thread-pool thread.

Comment: So does the await key word make something similar to a thread once its fired?

Comment: When would you use the thread pool Task.Factory.StartNew over the async and await?

Comment: @user3363744: No, `async` is the opposite of multithreading - it uses *fewer* threads instead of *more*. You would use the thread pool (`Task.Run`, not `StartNew`) if you have CPU-bound work you need to move off the UI thread.

Comment: One last thing, where is the return? how would I return a value of task if im not running Task.Factory.StartNew thread

Comment: If use the method you provided I freeze my main UI will the process takes place

Comment: If you want to return a value, have your method return `Task<T>` (e.g. `Task<string>`) instead of `Task` (in the method signature) and then return a value normally in the body of the method

Comment: If you want to do some processing and you don't want to keep the UI thread busy, then use `await Task.Run(...`. Use this just for the code that wants to do some CPU-bound work, not for the code that wants to access the UI.